# Expected number of tosses to get T,T

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume a coin has a probability p to get a head H. Suppose a coin is tossed until the partern T,T appear in the last 2 tosses. Once he got T,T then the game is finished. What is the expected number of flips is expected for the game?

I tried to find out the distribution of $N$ where $N$ stands for the expected value of the no. of tosses before getting T,T, but i don't know what kind of distribution is that, seems need another apporaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distribution is not needed. Call $n$ the expected number of tosses needed to reach TT and $m$ the expected number of tosses needed to reach TT **starting from T**. Conditioning on the value of the first toss, one gets $n=1+(1-p)m+pn$ and $m=1+pn+(1-p)0$. Which yields 
$$
n=\frac{2-p}{(1-p)^2}=\frac1{1-p}+\frac1{(1-p)^2}.
$$
*Sanity checks:* $n=2$ for $p=0$ (why?), $n\to\infty$ when $p\to1$ (why?) and the function $p\mapsto n$ is nondecreasing (why?).

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139699/what-are-some-examples-of-a-mathematical-result-being-counterintuitive/139795#139795) be the same problem? But this is yielding a different result.

Comment: @StefanHansen Here the probability of Heads is $p$ and he looks for TT, in the other example, he looks for $HH$ for which heads has prob $p$. Substitute $q=1-p$ in the above to get what you have on the other page.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: i have a question, why $m=(1-p)+pn$ why it isn't correct? As i have p probability has to restart and 1-p probability to have an expectation of 1. Thx

Comment: If one needs to restart, the duration is `1+n`, not `n`. This happens with probability `p` hence `m = (1-p)1 + p(1+n) = 1 + pn`.

Comment: o i see. thanks