# Concrete solution to the (oriented) Oberwolfach problem with one table

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, puzzle

The oriented Oberwolfach problem (with only one table) and its solution are the following.

In a meeting of $n$ people during $n-1$ days (combinatorists at Oberwolfach for concreteness), they all have diner around one table.
As they only speak to their right neighbour, everybody wants to be seated each day with a different right neighbour. For which $n$ is this possible?

The answer is : this is always possible unless $n=4$ or $n=6$, as stated in this other question [Round-robin party presents (or: Graeco-Latin square with additional cycle property)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552096/round-robin-party-presents-or-graeco-latin-square-with-additional-cycle-proper) .

This can be rephrased abstractly in terms of graph theory, see the answer to the question above.

My question is : if $n=p$ is a prime, then one can use multiplication by the $p-1$ units in $\mathbf F_p$ to build a solution.

However, for other values of $n$, I don't know (and I didn't find it in the papers solving the problem, although it must be in there somewhere) how to build solutions.

For example, can anyone explain to me how to build a solution for $n=8$ (if possible with a strategy no too *ad hoc*)?